# Select distinct join in HQL Request

Tags: select, join, hql, distinct

I have a bit complicated request to do in HQL and I don't manage to obtain the result I want.

Here is what I want to do :

I have two entities t1 and t2 with a OneToMany relation between both.
I want to select some infos from both tables in the same request but here is the issue, I don't want any duplicate of t1.

So basically I want 4 properties, 3 from t1 and 1 from t2, but as there are several records from t2 for the same t1 object, I just want to get the first from t2 to not have any t1 duplicated records.

Here is what I did : 
SELECT DISTINCT(t1.a , t1.b, t1.c, t2.z) FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2

But Obviously, that worked when I did not need any t2 parameter, but now I have some records (a,b,c) duplicated for different t2.z

And I don't find any way in HQL to do it (I can't do any Select LIMIT 1 that could work in SQL).

Does anybody have an idea on how to resolve that?

Thanks

Comment: I was facing same problem using hibernate on **Grails** this helped me: `resultTransformer org.hibernate.Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY`

Comment: The thing is we are not using criteria for now. We are migrating to it but for now we are using google genericdao